# Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo

Tags: android, performance

Why can't the dalvikvm find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo ?

```
08-15 15:19:45.112: D/dalvikvm(319): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x008b
08-15 15:19:45.112: I/dalvikvm(319): Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo,
  referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
08-15 15:19:45.112: W/dalvikvm(319): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 417:Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;
  .loadLogo (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/actionbarsherlock/GnAJdV6LtCc/izSc8pRFTYgJ) posted a problem with this on a different site. His solution was:

Got it. Found no applied style which causes my problem but found a workaround for this...
Directly after applying the style via setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
i'm using the following code to set the background color.

```
   View v = act.getWindow().getDecorView();

   if (v != null){
       v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.abs__background_holo_dark);
   }
```

Now everything is working like expected.

Answer (score 0):

[`loadLogo()` is new to API Level 9](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#loadLogo%28android.content.pm.PackageManager%29). If you are running this on API Level 8 or below, you will get this warning.