# Error: Where is getActivityLogo in package manager?

Tags: android

```
03-23 23:28:04.490: I/dalvikvm(275): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
```

Hello! I get the above error while running my code ADT:22.6.1 SDK:4.4.2 
I don't know what the problem is and I'm new to Android development. I tried to run the code provided by mybringback at youtube. But it's not running.

I referred to one post provided showing background change code, but that also does not work.

change worked but again some errors:

```
03-23 16:13:24.390: D/AndroidRuntime(947): Shutting down VM
03-23 16:13:24.390: W/dalvikvm(947): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a9cba8)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 947
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.StartingPoint}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.example.myfirstapp.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:36)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-23 16:13:24.410: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  ... 11 more
03-23 16:13:33.790: I/Process(947): Sending signal. PID: 947 SIG: 9
03-23 16:18:06.983: D/AndroidRuntime(1155): Shutting down VM
03-23 16:18:06.983: W/dalvikvm(1155): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a9cba8)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 1155
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.StartingPoint}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at com.example.myfirstapp.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:36)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-23 16:18:07.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     ... 11 more
03-23 16:23:07.463: I/Process(1155): Sending signal. PID: 1155 SIG: 9
```

code:
**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your total is:"
        android:id="@+id/tvdisplay"
         />
     <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Add one"        
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/badd"
         />
      <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Subtract one"        
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/bsub" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**mainactivity.java**

```
package com.example.mysecondapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter;
    Button add,sub;
    TextView display;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();       
        }
        display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);
        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.badd);
        sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bsub);


         add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counter++;
                    display.setText("Your total is" + counter);

                }
         });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Which support library? Sorry, I'm new so dont know much, but i opened up the PackageManager Class, couldnt find the method

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256140/could-not-find-method-android-content-pm-applicationinfo-loadlogo

Comment: which is your line no 36 in the StartingPoint.java??

Comment: It is onclick method of a button

Comment: dubug this and comment this if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();       
        } code and run your app first see what it is shwoing

Comment: update me once you do this is it still throwing some error or exception

Comment: it works fine..but when I remove comments of the click event, it shows following errors in addition to previous ones:03-24 03:13:09.659: D/dalvikvm(1221): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-24 03:13:11.139: D/dalvikvm(1221): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-24 03:13:12.389: D/AndroidRuntime(1221): Shutting down VM

Comment: can u send me sample of the app so that i can debug that completely

Comment: Hey thanx, but I just changed whole code and all libraries to what mentioned in tutorial. And now its working.. Because what given in tutorial has only one xml, while my project had two.. Don't know why.. confused as I'm a newbie..

Comment: no issues you will learn in some time ..keep it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call was [introduced in API level 9](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getActivityLogo%28android.content.Intent%29). This means your application manifest requires a `minSdkVersion` value of at least 9.

Ensure your AndroidManifest.xml has min/target versions similar to this - probably, your current `minSdkVersion` is 8 or below.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: You're getting a NullPointerException in your activities `onCreate`. Without that code we can't be of any help.